# Shader issues with Pyglet

Tags: python, shader, sprite, pyglet

So. I have been using Pyglet for up to a week at this point and have been making a Rhythm Game. I decided to test some shaders using the ShaderPy library for pyglet. The shader applies and works, but all sprites and images appear as black rectangles. I am drawing images using image.load(). I have tried researching the topic to now luck, I am not very used to OpenGl shaders and textures. Though I did read that once a shader is binded, all rendering is passed to it, but I couldn't find any more information to help.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
import shaderpy

# image
image = pyglet.image.load('image.png')

# window
window = pyglet.window.Window(1280,720)
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0.5,0,0,1)

# shader
shader = shaderpy.Shader([('shader.vs', GL_VERTEX_SHADER), 
('shader.fs', GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)])

@window.event
def on_draw():
    shader.bind()
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0,0)
    shader.unbind()

pyglet.app.run()
```

This code produces a black square for me where the image is supposed to be.

Comment: Which shader files (vertex and fragment) are you using? What is their content? They might compile, but do they really work as expected?

Comment: Here's what I did. I installed the shaderpy module, and tried to open the `__init__.py` file. Inside this file, the function `glVertexAttribPointer` is never called. This function basically informs the vertex and fragment shaders about the Texture Coordinates of the Mesh. So if this function is never called, the shaders have no idea where to draw the image. Maybe that's why it shows a black square.

Comment: What you can do about it: try using another shader module that calls this OpenGL method. And try to bind this shader module with the shader script using proper vertex data. If this is difficult to understand, try creating your own shader module. There's lots of tutorials out there, mostly in C++, but they will teach you how to do it. https://learnopengl.com/ is one of them.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? [Pyglet odd shader behavior while using ShaderPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672698/pyglet-odd-shader-behavior-while-using-shaderpy). Repeating question to attract attention is not welcome. Try to improve your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Where is the shader code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The Pyglet documentation recommends using [PyShaders](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/external_resources.html#pyshaders). How do you know what `image.blit(0,0)` is doing? How can you assume that your shader works with the internals of `image.blit(0,0)`. As far as I know the the current pyglet [release](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/releases) uses legacy OpenGL.

Comment: I redid the question not for attention, but the original post was insufficient in detail surrounding the scripts. So I made a new post with better detail so it wouldn’t be taken down, sorry. I’m new to this website

Comment: But thanks everyone for suggestions! I will try and use PyShaders like suggested

Comment: Likely the problem is the shader. Why do you not show the shader? You must use a GLSL version 1.20 shader.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I deleted the other post, this is the only one that exists

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried a different shader, it worked. But it only affected the black squares, still no images

Comment: Why don't you show the shaders?

Comment: I will edit it rq, give me a sec